# TwinCAT 3.1 fCoE read and write with Complete Access

Tags: twincat, ethercat

I am attempting to perform complete access read and writes to an EtherCAT slave controller using TwincAT 3.1 on Windows 10.

Generated EtherCAT Slave Stack Code using the Beckhoff Slave Stack Code Tool 5.12. Successfully able to enter operational state using TwinCAT 3.1 as EtherCAT master. I have a mailbox object at index 0x8001, which is an array of 25 bytes. I am unable to perform complete access, which allows writing / reading all 25 bytes from the object at 0x8001. Without the complete access, I will have to write to each sub-index of the index 0x8001 individually.This means 25 separate read/ write operation at each sub-index under the object.

I have tried using EC Engineer 3.06 from Acontis technologies as EtherCAT master, and I verified that the complete accesses are functional. 
Does anyone know how to perform complete access using TwinCAT?

Answer (score 0):

Twincat does it automatically if the ESI file has the complete access flag.

Comment: I want to be able to perform a write with complete access and cannot find a button/window that allows to do so. Is there any documentation / link that I may be able to look at?